# How to make prediction for a tensor flow model?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

The model is trained and evaluated but what I want is to make predictions. I know model.predict() can be used for the tf.Learn API but is there any other way to predict the values? How to predict the values if regular input is coming i.e in case of live traffic? 
Here is the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
TF documentation tells you how to use a trained model for predictions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Predicting the tensorflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638697/predicting-the-tensorflow-model)